# Multivariate $t$ ('mvt') - adjustment in emmeans in R

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, multivariate-distribution

I am doing post-hoc comparisons of contrasts based on linear mixed models I built in R. I am using the [`emmeans`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html) package for the comparisons. One of the default adjustment methods for multiple correction is "mvt" which stands for "multivariate $t$". However, I cannot find a good explanantion of this method. Is there a paper available I can cite?

Comment: I'd recommend expanding the question a little. Say, for example, what mvt stands for (it can be found in the documentation/vignettes and help files of the package). Include the explanations that the authors offers (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/confidence-intervals.html), for example) as a quote so that all readers are on the same page. Don't expect that readers here will google the terms and the package on their own.

Comment: Simply put, the method estimates a multivariate t distribution of all your hypotheses which it uses to generate p-values. The multivariate approach takes into consideration the correlation of the hypotheses.